# How to write code for browser tab change flutter web only

Tags: flutter

I am using below code for listening to the browser tab change detection for `flutter web`.

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

js.context.callMethod('addEventListener', [
      'visibilitychange',
          (event) {
        final isVisible =
            js.context.callMethod('eval', ['document.hidden']) != true;
        handleTabChange(isVisible);
      }
]);
```

This above code is working fine when i am trying to run in flutter web, but when i try to build mobile app, it is preventing because of the `js package` which is not supported for flutter mobile.

I want your help to know that how can i achieve this same for `WEB-ONLY` so that i can able to run this for web only and mobile app can be ignored this functionality.

Comment: i think you should separate the file. since we cant use condtional import  : https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34262#issuecomment-416129832

Comment: but if you separete them, you can use `kIsWeb` from `foundation.dart`